# How can i use the Hash table to count the appears of an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, count, hashmap, hashtable

I have to implement a function in only javascript lenguage.

i have three arrays with day, month and year of a date.

```
    var arrayDay= [];
    var arrayMonth = [];
    var arrayYear = [];
    var indexOfDate = [];
    var countAppears = [];
```

And I want to see how many times a date appear in this array of object, and i have to do this for every date in the array of object;

i do this;

```
for(var i=0;i<arrayYear.length;i++){
indexOfDate.push(i);
countAppears.push(group(arrayYear[i],arrayMonth [i],
arrayDay[i]));
}


function group(year, month, day){
var cont=0;
    for(var x=0;x<=arrayYear.lenght;x++){
        if(arrayYear[x] == year && arrayMonth[x] == month && 
        arrayDay[x] == day){
          cont++;
        }
    }
    return cont;
}
```

after that i have to compile two array, i need the firt contain the date object and the second the quantity of the appears of this date.

How can i do that with an HASH TABLE??

sorry for my english.

Comment: Please share the code that you have tried so far.

Comment: now there is the code i do, con you help me? @AmitGupta

Comment: can you provide your input and expected result

Comment: @DibashSapkota my input is a lot of date (day/month/year) 
The expected result
array that contain how many times a date appears in the array